# Error starting Bind9.11.3 with dlz_bind for Samba

Tags: linux, samba, bind

I'm configuring a samba server that will migrate from Zentyal (replication of ldap then demote Zentyal).
I configured bind which works until I implement

```
dlz "AD DNS Zone" {
    database "dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/bind9/dlz_bind9_11.so"; };
```

in the "/etc/bind/named.conf.local" file and

```
dlz "AD DNS Zone" {
    # For BIND 9.11.0
     database "dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/bind9/dlz_bind9_11.so"; };
```

The error for

```
service bind9 start
```

is:

```
 /usr/local/samba/lib/bind9/dlz_bind9_11.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

If I comment the block in "/etc/bind/named.conf.local", bind9 works.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't use Zentyal, I had the same error while spending the day setting up Samba 4.7.6 on Ubuntu 18.04 and the previously working bind 9.11.3 would fail to start.

For some files it was file ownership needed to be corrected (i.e. `chown root:bind ...`) but the main problem was AppArmor blocking named from accessing libraries it needed for the dlopen command.

As described in this Samba wiki page [BIND9 DLZ AppArmor and SELinux Integration](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/BIND9_DLZ_AppArmor_and_SELinux_Integration)

> If you are using AppArmor or SELinux, you have to ensure that the BIND
>   process has read access to the following files:
>
> - /usr/local/samba/private/dns.keytab
> - /usr/local/samba/private/named.conf
>
> as well read-write access to the
>
> - /usr/local/samba/private/dns/
>
> directory and it's own zone file(s).

The below settings are based upon the above Samba Wiki page, with corrections for my file paths and some that seem to be missing from the documentation. Following the link, this information is near the bottom.

> AppArmor Configuration :
>
> Add the following to the end of /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named
>   (create it if it doesn't already exist).

```
# Samba DLZ and Active Directory Zones (default source installation)
/var/lib/samba/private/dns.keytab r,
/var/lib/samba/private/named.conf r,
/var/lib/samba/private/dns/** rwk,
/var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb rwk,
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/bind9/** rm,
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/ldb/** rm,
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/** rm,
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ldb/** rm,
```

(In the original `/var/lib/samba/` was mapped to `/usr/local/samba/`) All the `/usr/lib/` paths came from errors bind/AppArmor continued to throw afterwards, you may or may not need them.

After creating that file and restarting AppArmor, starting bind worked again.